# Is there an alternative method to find out which feature belongs to which image?

Tags: image, image-processing

I'm working on an algorithm in which near-duplicate images are detected. I extracted features from the training images and from the query image(to be it's near-duplicate detected). In the case that features of training database is hashed and nears of the query feature found(by approximate nearest-neighbor method), how do i say the computer "the features that you just found belongs to ... image"?

Comment: That would depend on your implementation of the code. Could you post the code you have implemented?

Comment: Hashing does not preserve proximity, so the nearest-neighbor must be found in feature space. Finding a ready-made NN classifier should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two methods:

- **Locally Sensitive Hashing (HSL)**: these are hash functions where the relative distance between the input values is preserved in the relative distance between the output hash values; input values that are closer to each other will produce output hash values that are closer to each other [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing)].
- **Siames networks: (SN)** A Siamese neural network (sometimes called a twin neural network) is an artificial neural network that uses the same weights while working in tandem on two different input vectors to compute comparable output vectors. Often one of the output vectors is precomputed, thus forming a baseline against which the other output vector is compared. This is similar to comparing fingerprints but can be described more technically as a distance function for locality-sensitive hashing. They are used in things as recognizing handwritten checks, automatic detection of faces in camera images (e.g, DeepFace), and matching queries with indexed documents [[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_neural_network)].

read following links for more information or implementation:

- [LSH2](https://orangedatamining.com/widget-catalog/text-mining/similarityhashing/), [LHS3](https://towardsdatascience.com/fast-near-duplicate-image-search-using-locality-sensitive-hashing-d4c16058efcb)
- [SN1](https://pyimagesearch.com/2020/11/30/siamese-networks-with-keras-tensorflow-and-deep-learning/)